# Number of partitions of an arbitrary set by an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

My textbook states :

> Given an arbitrary equivalence relation $R$ in an arbitrary set $X$, $R$ divides $X$ into mutually disjoint subsets $A_i$ called partitions or subdivisions of $X$ .

But I'm wondering if there exists any formula or something to predict how many such partitions may be formed.

Comment: Each equivalence class creates exactly one partition.

Comment: @William my book gives the example of the partitioning of the set of  integers into the set of even and odd integers via the relation $R = \{(a,b) :2|(a-b) \}$.

Comment: @Ramanujan_π Are you interested in the number of partitions on a set that can be labeled as the partition induced by an equivalence relation? For *every* partition we can find a (unique) corresponding equivalence relation (just state that $xRy$ iff $x,y$ are members of the same element of the partition). There is a on-to-one relation between partitions on a set and equivalence relations on a set.

Comment: Then have a look here: [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions).